# "An error occurred while trying to copy a file: The source file is corrupted."

Tags: windows, git, installation, git-bash

How can I solve this error during installation of git-bash on Windows?

I have downloaded git-bash and I want to install it but when it show me that  error like the picture down below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHnwb.jpg]

```
An error occurred while trying to copy a file:  
The source file is corrupted.
```

Answer (score 1):

If, after a full reboot, the same installation process still fails, you do have the option to:

- uncompress the [latest release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) in its portable form: [`PortableGit-2.27.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.27.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.27.0-64-bit.7z.exe)
- add its folder to your %PATH%

I generally add:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer   i will try your solution